# wow.js in Ruby on Rails with Webpack and Yarn

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack, wow.js

I am pretty new to rails. I wish to add some cool transition effects on my landing page using wow.js (https://github.com/matthieua/WOW)

I installed wow.js using yarn add wow.js

I created a new wow.js in my javascript asset pipeline with the following

```js
import {WOW} from 'wowjs'

const wow = new WOW({
  boxClass: 'wow',
  animateClass: 'animated',
  offset: 0,
  live: true
});

wow.init()
```

I import wow.js in my application.js file (import '../components/wow')

I added to my webpage the css wow tags.

However, the effects do not work on my webpage. I get the following error message:

> MutationObserver is not supported by your browser.
>   wow.js:130 WOW.js cannot detect dom mutations, please call `.sync()` after loading new content.

Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Thanks a lot for your help,

Chris

Comment: https://github.com/matthieua/WOW/issues/166

Answer (score 0):

I found the (simple) answer to my problem.
Basically I just needed to 
 - turn live to false to stop the js error message 
 - include the Animate.css in my webpage, which is actually the code responsible for the transition effects (js only triggers with Event Listener)